# Error in formatting the POST URL,because of spaces inside the parameter

Tags: javascript

Hi All
I am building an URL which is stored as varible to be available for a tab on clicking as below.

The parmeters of the URL are some constants and strings.
So in one param the user has entered in the Textarea coulmn as

```
This is
to be
removed 
immediately
```

and so on build of URL the browser is throwing 'unterminated string literal'

Below is the URL as seen in 'view source'

```
<script type="text/javascript">var tab3700Action = "/PM/action/showTaskCompletionStatus?preventSTIES=
&deadlinedate=4/22/2005&date=4/21/2005&orggroup=27&effectivedate=4/22/2005&taskid=2
&comments=This is
to be
removed 
immediately&selected_taskid=2&orgfilterDISP=&taskname=Recall Meat
&equation=&tasktypeid=283&successRedirectAction=showTaskCompletionSummary
&estimatedduration=2:00&org=545";
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`encodeURIComponent`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_encodeURIComponent.asp):

```
var realQueryString = encodeURIComponent(queryString);
```

Answer (score 1):

str = str.replace(/\s/g,"%20");

Answer (score 1):

use

[Javascript url decode, encode](http://www.webtoolkit.info/javascript-url-decode-encode.html)

```
/**
*
*  URL encode / decode
*  http://www.webtoolkit.info/
*
**/

var Url = {

    // public method for url encoding
    encode : function (string) {
        return escape(this._utf8_encode(string));
    },

    // public method for url decoding
    decode : function (string) {
        return this._utf8_decode(unescape(string));
    },

    // private method for UTF-8 encoding
    _utf8_encode : function (string) {
        string = string.replace(/\r\n/g,"\n");
        var utftext = "";

        for (var n = 0; n < string.length; n++) {

            var c = string.charCodeAt(n);

            if (c < 128) {
                utftext += String.fromCharCode(c);
            }
            else if((c > 127) && (c < 2048)) {
                utftext += String.fromCharCode((c >> 6) | 192);
                utftext += String.fromCharCode((c & 63) | 128);
            }
            else {
                utftext += String.fromCharCode((c >> 12) | 224);
                utftext += String.fromCharCode(((c >> 6) & 63) | 128);
                utftext += String.fromCharCode((c & 63) | 128);
            }

        }

        return utftext;
    },

    // private method for UTF-8 decoding
    _utf8_decode : function (utftext) {
        var string = "";
        var i = 0;
        var c = c1 = c2 = 0;

        while ( i < utftext.length ) {

            c = utftext.charCodeAt(i);

            if (c < 128) {
                string += String.fromCharCode(c);
                i++;
            }
            else if((c > 191) && (c < 224)) {
                c2 = utftext.charCodeAt(i+1);
                string += String.fromCharCode(((c & 31) << 6) | (c2 & 63));
                i += 2;
            }
            else {
                c2 = utftext.charCodeAt(i+1);
                c3 = utftext.charCodeAt(i+2);
                string += String.fromCharCode(((c & 15) << 12) | ((c2 & 63) << 6) | (c3 & 63));
                i += 3;
            }

        }

        return string;
    }

}
```